# Swift Charts Plotting

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I am wondering how I can plot Y(X) and X.
An attempt is given below. Any suggestion/tips is highly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts
struct ContentView: View {
    let Y = [1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5]
    let X = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
    var body: some View {
        let YX = Array(zip(Y,X))
        Chart {
            ForEach(YX, id: \.self) { (sample,sample2) in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("", sample),
                    y: .value("", sample2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a struct instead of a tuple

```
struct YX: Hashable {
    let y: Double
    let x: Double
}
```

And create it using `map`

```
var body: some View {
    let yx = Array(zip(Y,X)).map(YX.init)
    Chart {
        ForEach(yx, id: \.self) { value in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("", value.x),
                y: .value("", value.y))
        }
    }
}
```